# Keras DataGenerator with a validation set smaller than batch size make no validation

Tags: python, keras

I wrote a DataGenerator and initialized a validation_generator. If the batch size specified for training is larger than the size of the validation set, no validation loss/acc is calculated.

If the validation set is larger, everything works fine. Specifying validation_steps does not help.

```
# Create data generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], embedding_model, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], embedding_model, **params)

# create LSTM
model = get_LSTM_v1(seq_length, input_dim, hot_enc_dim)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train LSTM
history = model.fit_generator(
    generator=training_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    epochs=n_epochs,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    workers=cpu_cores
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataGenerator` may need to be modified in order to return a partial batch when the batch size is smaller than the size of the validation set.

Most of the time, the number of computable batches returned by the generator correspond to the floor of the division of the number of samples by the batch size. This would return zero if the batch size is bigger than the size of the set.

You could try to work around by repeating the data in order to have enough for a full batch when needed.